# How to start a __name__ == '__main__': with specific inputs from another .py file?

Tags: python, loops, file, optimization, program-entry-point

I have a main.py in which a

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

is located to start the whole process.
insted a normal `def main()` i need to use the    `if __name__ == '__main__':` variante, because i am coding in spyder AND using multiprocessing at the same time (which would result in a mess otherwise).

I need to be able to just run this main.py file. (which works just fine, BUT...)

However at the same time i need to be able to call this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

from outside by another .py file (lets call it optimize.py) with an optimizing loop to give the main.py different parameters.

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sure. Put the stuff you have below your condition into a function with parameters and call that from other modules.

Comment: Create a `main` function and call it from `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function that you call from your `if __name__ == '__main__':` condition:

Before:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 5 
    j = 20
    m = 99
    # do A with i
    # do B with j
    # do C with m
```

After:

```
def start_me(i,j,m):
    # do A with i
    # do B with j
    # do C with m


if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 5 
    j = 20
    m = 99
    start_me(i,j,m)
```

If called directly it works with default parameters, if called from `optimizer.py` you simly use the function directly and provide parameters as you want.

Comment: what in this case would be the "loop.py" and what the "main.py"

Comment: @benoid both are main.py (once before, once after changes)- in loop.py you would do somehting like `from main import start_me` +  `start_me(99,88,77)`

Comment: when I import this py file: doesnt the "if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 5 
    j = 20
    m = 99
    start_me(i,j,m)" get called too then? (would be executing it twice)

Comment: @Benoid the whole point of `if __name__ == '__main__':` is that when you do an `import yourfilename` in some other file, the `__name__`  is NOT `'__main__'`  but in that case is `yourfilename` ... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)